# Linux & macOs on Mac Mini

Tags: dual-boot

I've installed Ubuntu (22.04.) on my mac Mini (late 2012) and in addition just installed an older macOS on a separate partition. When i power on, macOS boots automatically. If I press Alt I can choose from both systems. Since I had Ubuntu as main work OS in mind, which I will use more often, I'd rather like Ubuntu to start from pole position.

So is it possible to switch the boot order, so that Ubuntu starts automatically and if I want macOS to boot, I have to explicitly choose it?

Regards,
JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a boot loader for that, such as rEFInd. I successfully dual-booted macOS High Sierra and Linux Mint 21 on an old iMac (Late 2009 I think it was), using [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/#install-refind).
In rEFInd's config, you can adjust which OS to boot by default.

Another option would be OpenCore, which I think is more modern. You could even install something like macOS Monterey or Ventura via [OCLP](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html#mac-mini).